# Cannot read property 'definitions' of undefined in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the below code, There is nothing like `definitions` but still got this error as:

```
 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'definitions' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'definitions' of undefined
```

See the below code:

**dashboard.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit,HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { slideAnimation } from './animations/animations';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector:'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ],
    animations: [ slideAnimation ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

@HostBinding('@routeAnimation') routeAnimation = true;
@HostBinding('style.display')   display = 'block';
@HostBinding('style.position')  position = 'absolute';

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
 }
```

**animation.ts:**

```
import { animate, AnimationEntryMetadata, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/core';
export const slideInDownAnimation: AnimationEntryMetadata =
  trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('*',
      style({
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })
    )
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got The answer:

I should use

`import { slideInDownAnimation } from './animations/animations';`

instead

`import { SomthingElse } from './animations/animations';`

wherever I want to import.